# RoR - Download ZIP file using gmail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail, zip

I am trying to set up some rake tasks.  It requires me to connect to gmail and download a Zip file which is sent as an attachment.

I have written the following code(which works fine for downloading csv) -

```
gmail = Gmail.connect(ENV["USERNAME"], ENV["PASSWORD"])
msg = gmail.inbox.find(from: ENV["REC_USER"], 
  subject: args[:subject])
dir_path = "lib/mfu_payment_data/"
Dir.mkdir dir_path unless File.exists?(dir_path)

if msg.first
  msg.first.attachments.each do |attachment|
   File.write(File.join(dir_path,attachment.filename),attachment.body.decoded)
  end
end
```

It throws the following error -

```
rake aborted! 
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xED" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

I assume that this has got something to do with the attachment.body.decoded, but I do not know how else to do this.

Comment: You could try writing in binary mode: `File.open(File.join(...), 'wb') { |file| file.write(attachment.body.decoded) }`

Comment: Thank you!!  Your suggestion worked.  :)
Please do put it in the answers section so that I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try writing the file in binary mode:

```
File.open('/path/to/file;, 'wb') { |file| file.write(attachment.body.decoded) }
```

`"b"`  Binary file mode
     Suppresses EOL <-> CRLF conversion on Windows. And
     sets external encoding to ASCII-8BIT unless explicitly
     specified.

The modes are described in the [IO](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-new) class which `File` inherits from.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have many option to generate zip file

[Download and unzip](http://emmanueloga.com/2011/06/21/dowloading-and-unzipping-a-file.html)

Comment: Hey Sunny,  I don't want to generate the zip file.  I want to download it.  Does downloading imply, generating zip file and then downloading?

Comment: firstly you should generate zip file then download it I am just adding code for that also